# LibGdx Label text wrap bug?

Tags: java, libgdx

I use a Label with text wrap enabled. In this case, the text wraps wrong. The text wraps into 3 lines, when it should be only 2 and the Label size only reflects the 2 lines. I debugged through the code and found the reason for this to be in the Label.layout() method. Not sure if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong.

In the code below you can see that the text is set twice to the GlyphLayout. The first time it wraps correct, the second time we use the reduced width and it wraps into more lines as before. I think the second time we set the text into the GlyphLayout, the same width should be used.

```
public class Label extends Widget {

   public void layout () {
      ...

      float width = getWidth(), height = getHeight();
      ...

      GlyphLayout layout = this.layout;
      float textWidth, textHeight;
      if (wrap || text.indexOf("\n") != -1) {
         // Set the text into the GlyphLayout. The text is wrapped correctly here
         layout.setText(font, text, 0, text.length, Color.WHITE, width, lineAlign, wrap, ellipsis);
         textWidth = layout.width;
         textHeight = layout.height;

         ...
      } else {
         textWidth = width;
         textHeight = font.getData().capHeight;
      }

      ...

      // Set the text again into the GlyphLayout. This time with the width that we got when we set it the first time
      // This time the text is wrapped wrong as it uses less width as it should
      layout.setText(font, text, 0, text.length, Color.WHITE, textWidth, lineAlign, wrap, ellipsis);
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to `invalidate()` the label and then `pack()` the label so it calculates any new preferred sizes; this may or may not fix the problem.

Looking at the source code of `Label` then you can see that the last invocation of `layout.setText()` is always invoked regardless of text wrapping or not.

The previous `layout.setText()` invocation is used to set the `textWidth` and `textHeight` for the later call where those values are actually used.

If wrapping is on or there is a newline character then the width and height is set to that of the label and if it is off then the width is set to the actual text width and the height set to the font data height.

From the above, another problem that may be causing this to happen is if you have scaled the font and/or label. The scaling factor is not being applied from within `Label.layout()` which may cause the label size to be that of 2 lines whilst the actual text is 3 lines as the width doesn't allow for overflow with wrapping set to on.

If all else fails, I would ensure that your font files are correct and that there are not any characters or data in your text that may cause a new line to occur.

I would also suggest to use another font of the same glyph width and height and see if the problem persists. If it does not then at least you know it is a problem relating to the font and not the label.

Hope this helped you.

Comment: I have never seen that before either. It only happens in this one case. I'm a bit confused, prefSize is a private field in Label and cannot be set from the outside. It gets calculated inside the Label. Also, I am not setting any width or height to the Label anyways. It is nested in a Table and gets it width from there. The height is calculated from the text and in how many lines it wraps.

Comment: Also, i do understand that the first time layout.setText() is called to get the text width and height, but why is this reduced size used the second time? We still have the same size available. If we use a different width and height the second time, it can be expected that the text will break down differently, is it not?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! Unfortunately that did not help. I actually pinned it down to a floating point problem in the text wrapping. Turns out that in Java `251.40002f + 10.8f - 10.8f = 251.40001f` and there lies the problem that causes the last word of my line to break down the second time layout.setText() is called

Comment: Nice find, sorry I could not of helped.

Comment: No worries. I appreciate that there are folks around that want to help!

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved in libgdx 1.9.12